How to Quickly Scale SageMaker Async Endpoint from 0 to 1 Instance for a Single Request?
Currently, I am working on an AWS SageMaker and I have to scale an async endpoint from 0 to 1 for processing a single request. This is same with the aim of maintaining cost efficiency where instances are not to run if there are no incoming requests. I have configured the auto-scaling policies but I am having problem with the timing of the start of scaling up when a request comes in.
Here are some details about my current setup:
Using SageMaker async endpoints
The auto-scaling policies are set according to the HasBacklog metric.
We also tasted a latency issue when scaling the services from 0 to 1 instance
Here is the code snippet I am using to configure the auto-scaling policy:
scaling_policy = application_scaling.put_scaling_policy(
    PolicyName=policy_name,
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker",  # The namespace of the service that provides the resource.
    ResourceId=resource_id,  # Endpoint name
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",  
    PolicyType="TargetTrackingScaling",
    TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
        'TargetValue': 1.0,
        'CustomizedMetricSpecification': {
            'MetricName': 'HasBacklogWithoutCapacity',
            'Namespace': 'AWS/SageMaker',
            'Dimensions': [
                {'Name': 'EndpointName', 'Value': endpoint_name}
            ],
            'Statistic': 'Average',
        },
        'ScaleInCooldown': 60,
        'ScaleOutCooldown': 10,
    }
)

I also tried StepScaling, here is the code snippet:
scaleout_policy_name = f"{endpoint_name}-ScalingoutPolicy"

scalingout_policy = application_scaling.put_scaling_policy(
    PolicyName=scaleout_policy_name,
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker",
    ResourceId=resource_id,
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",
    PolicyType="StepScaling",
    StepScalingPolicyConfiguration={
        'AdjustmentType': 'ChangeInCapacity',
        'StepAdjustments': [
            {
                'MetricIntervalLowerBound': 0,
                # 'MetricIntervalUpperBound': 10.0,
                'ScalingAdjustment': 1  
            },

        ],
        'Cooldown': 30, 
        'MetricAggregationType': 'Average'
    }
)

scaleout_alarm_name = f"{endpoint_name}-ScalingoutAlarm"
scale_out_policy_arn = scalingout_policy['PolicyARN']

scalingout_alarm = cloudwatch_client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName=scaleout_alarm_name,
    MetricName='HasBacklogWithoutCapacity',
    Namespace='AWS/SageMaker',
    Statistic='Average',
    Period=60,  # Period in seconds
    EvaluationPeriods=1,
    Threshold=1.0, 
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'EndpointName',
            'Value': endpoint_name
        },
        {
            'Name': 'VariantName',
            'Value': 'AllTraffic'
        }
    ],
    AlarmActions=[
        scale_out_policy_arn
    ],
    AlarmDescription='Alarm for scaling out SageMaker endpoint instances',
    Unit='Count'
)


Can you suggest a better way or an advice that can help to reduce the latency time when we switch from 0 instance to 1 for a single request with async SageMaker? Is it possible to speed up the scaling process some configurations and optimizations?
